# The best practice to create a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I want to create a dataset for human posture recognition, I record a set of video then I extract a frames from each video, then I classify each frame in the corresponding posture. But the problem is for example for the stand posture I record 3 min video for training and validation set, each posture 3 min video for validation and training set for x posture. The problem I can figure after, I will get the same number of examples in training and validation set (Example : 1000 examples train and 1000 val), this can cause me problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when you are classifying data you will have more training data than the validation set, in my case I have generally aspire for 75% of the data as training, and 25% of the data for validation. Although in your case your training data seems large enough that any outliers in the data won't affect your classification algorithm. It doesn't matter if the training set even had less data than the validation set, as long as the training set is large enough to sufficiently train your algorithm and not be affected by the outliers.

Comment: But If I have the same number of examples in the training and validation set ? (1000 train, 1000 val)

Comment: The training and validation sets are completely independent from each other. The more examples you have in the training set, the more accurate your algorithm will be. The more examples in your validation set, then the more accurately you will be able to see how well your algorithm has learned from the training data you gave it. So 1000 examples of training data means that your algorithm will be pretty accurate, and 100 examples of validation data means that you will get a very good understanding of how accurate your algorithm is after your training phase.

Comment: Yes then the same number of examples on train and val will not cause me problems, Thank you very much for your response @Palagino

Comment: They won't at all. I'm very glad to help! Good luck with your machine learning @TCHERAKAmine